# How to check the cluster details of a given vector in k-means in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, word2vec

I am using the following code to cluster my word vectors using k-means clustering algorithm.

```
from sklearn import cluster
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load("word2vec_model")
X = model[model.wv.vocab]
clusterer = cluster.KMeans (n_clusters=6)
preds = clusterer.fit_predict(X)
centers = clusterer.cluster_centers_
```

Given a word in the word2vec vocabulary (e.g., `word_vector = model['jeep']`) I want to get its cluster ID and cosine distance to its cluster center.

I tried the following approach.

```
for i,j in enumerate(set(preds)):
    positions = X[np.where(preds == i)]
    print(positions)
```

However, it returns all the vectors in each cluster ID and not exactly what I am looking for.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Pro tip: to see the limitations of k-means on word vectors, find the most similar vectors to each cluster center. These are usually pretty nondescript words, indicating that the clusters are quite low quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After clustering you get the `labels_` for all of your input data (in the same order as your input data), i.e. `clusterer.labels_[model.wv.vocab['jeep'].index]` would give you the cluster to which `jeep` belongs.

You can calculate the cosine distance with with [`scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html)

```
cluster_index = clusterer.labels_[model.wv.vocab['jeep'].index]
print(distance.cosine(model['jeep'], centers[cluster_index]))
>> 0.6935321390628815
```

**Full code**

I don't know how your model looks like but let's use [`GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/).

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from sklearn import cluster
from scipy.spatial import distance

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)

# let's use a subset to accelerate clustering
X = model[model.wv.vocab][:40000]

clusterer = cluster.KMeans (n_clusters=6)
preds = clusterer.fit_predict(X)
centers = clusterer.cluster_centers_

cluster_index = clusterer.labels_[model.wv.vocab['jeep'].index]
print(cluster_index, distance.cosine(model['jeep'], centers[cluster_index]))
```

Comment: Hi, just wondering how to get cosine similarity, instead of cosine distance? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt!

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

model = Word2Vec(common_texts, size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

clustering_model = KMeans(n_clusters=2)

preds = clustering_model.fit_predict([model.wv.get_vector(w) for w in model.wv.vocab])
```

To get the prediction for cluster ID

```
>>> clustering_model.predict([model.wv.get_vector('computer')])
# array([1], dtype=int32)
```

To get cosine similarity between given word and cluster centers

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
>>> cosine_similarity(clustering_model.cluster_centers_, [model.wv.get_vector('computer')])

# array([[-0.07410881],
       [ 0.34881588]])
```